# Age check for the users

Tags: android, mobile-application

This is more of product related query rather than a coding related query. If you find it in appropriate for the platform just let me know I will take it off.

The app that I am making is meant to be used by adults only. I want to ban people under the age of 18 from using it.

What would be the best way to put a check. What I could think of is to let everyone download the app and ask users for the Facebook login. Then I can get the correct age from the Facebook graph API and can allow/ban a user.

Any thoughts/alternatives

Comment: you can't be sure they are really 18. People lie

Comment: the only thing You can do is, make the settings inside Your developer console for the content rating.....

Comment: You can get their information in the GMail account installed on their phone. So make sure they need to sign in before using your app.